# What's the proper name for the armored Volatile variants?

Tags: dying-light, dying-light-the-following

A new variant of the deadly Volatile was added in The Following DLC of Dying Light. These new variants have some kind of hardened shell or perhaps are wearing body armor when they died and reanimated. Whatever they are, they're deadlier than their base-game counterparts.

I've seen few people talk about them on forums but I've never seen them get assigned a name. What do you call these monstrosities?

I was also lucky enough to snap a photo of a strong and regular Volatile variant standing side-by-side[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [game Wiki](https://dyinglight.fandom.com/wiki/Volatile#Evolved_Volatile) calls these *Evolved Volatiles*:

> Evolved Volatiles are an evolution of the uncommon Volatile introduced with the release Dying Light: The Following.